# href="file://" doesn't work

Tags: html, file, href

I have a problem with:
    `href="file://"`
Well I want to point a link in html to file, in browser if I write like

```
 file:///K:/filename.pdf
```

It works to open a file, but if I point it to:

```
      href="http://file:///K:/AmberCRO%20SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf"
```

It doesn't work. link is changed to:

```
file///K:/AmberCRO%20SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf
```

The `colon` after file disappears. Any suggestions as to what to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do, pointing `href="http://file:///K:/AmberCRO%20SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf"`? It is invalid!

Comment: Suggestions ? Link your files relative to your webpage. `<a href="files/filename.pdf">` and store your file into `files/` folder. For example

Comment: `http` is a protocol pointing to a web ressource, same is `file` pointing to a local ressource - you can't use both in the href.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason your URL is being rewritten to `file///K:/AmberCRO%20SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf` is because you specified `http://file://`

The `http://` at the beginning is the protocol being used, and your browser is stripping out the second colon (:) because it is invalid.

**Note**

If you link to something like

```
<a href="file:///K:/yourfile.pdf">yourfile.pdf</a>
```

The above represents a link to a file called `k:/yourfile.pdf`  on the k: drive on *the machine* on which you are viewing the URL.

You can do this, for example the below creates a link to `C:\temp\test.pdf`

```
<a href="file:///C:/Temp/test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
```

**By specifying file:// you are indicating that this is a local resource. This resource is NOT on the internet.**

Most people do not have a K:/ drive.

But, if this is what you are trying to achieve, that's fine, but this is not how a "typical" link on a web page works, and you shouldn't being doing this unless everyone who is going to access your link has access to the (same?) K:/drive (this might be the case with a shared network drive).

You could try

```
<a href="file:///K:/AmberCRO-SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf">test.pdf</a>
<a href="AmberCRO-SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf">test.pdf</a>
<a href="2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf">test.pdf</a>
```

Note that `http://file:///K:/AmberCRO%20SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf` is a malformed

Answer (score 0):

`%20` is the space between AmberCRO SOP.

Try -

```
href="http://file:///K:/AmberCRO SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf"
```

Or rename the folder as AmberCRO-SOP and write it as -

```
href="http://file:///K:/AmberCRO-SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf"
```

Comment: @Touki I guess FireFox adds file:/// when you open local files on your hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Share your folder for "everyone" or some specific group and try this:

```html
<a href="file://YOURSERVERNAME/AmberCRO%20SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf"> Download PDF </a>
```

Comment: Technically it should be `file://///YOURSERVERNAME`. The `file://` is the protocol bit, the `/` is for the root, and the `//YOURSERVERNAME` is the server's network-address-thingy-that-I-can't-remember-the-name-of.

Answer (score 0):

Although the ffile:////.exe used to work (for example - some versions of early html 4) it appears html 5 disallows this.
Tested using the following:

```
<a href="ffile:///<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a> 
<a href="ffile://<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a> 
<a href="ffile:/<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a> 
<a href="ffile:<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a> 
<a href="ffile://///<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a> 
<a href="file://<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a> 
<a href="file:/<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a> 
<a href="file:<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a> 
<a href="ffile://///<path name>/<filename>.exe" TestLink /a>
```

as well as ...
1/ substituted the "ffile" with just "file"
2/ all the above variations with the http:// prefixed before the ffile or file.

The best I could see was there is a possibility that if one wanted to open (edit) or save the file, it could be accomplished.  However, the exec file would not execute otherwise.