# How to open file in local machine using chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In a **html** page in **web application** the **hyperlink** should open **file** which is in **local machine**.If the web page is opened in IE it is working,but in **chrome it is not opening.**

I have tried this in **anchor tag**:

```
href="Z:\WORK\Training\sample.pdf"
```

also tried this:

```
href="file:\\Z:\WORK\Training\sample.pdf"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [href="file://" doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837024/href-file-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Non-local web pages cannot access local files in Chrome or any modern web browser.

You can override this using [LocalLinks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida) (for Firefox), but it will only work in your own machine.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome console shows the error.

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:\\Z:\WORK\Training\sample.pdf
```

You are not allowed to open a local file in a remote web page for some secure reasons. Why would you want to open a file on your computer through a remote web page?

For solutions, you can upload your local files to the server you visit, or just build a local server and using something like `http://localhost/WORK/Training/sample.pdf` to link your file.