# How to link .html files

Tags: html, css, replit

Alright. I'm coding in `HTML` and I have gotten stumped on a problem.

I have 3 `HTML` files:

`main.html`, `buy.html`, and `CSS.css`

and I'm trying to figure out how I can put a link or hyperlink on `main.html` that redirects me to `buy.html`.

Edit: Ive been told that `buy.html` and `main.html` have to be in the same directory. How do you add the `buy.html` to the same directory as `main.html`?

For reference, im using [`repl.it`](https://repl.it/) for coding in `HTML`

Comment: Are they in the same directory?

Comment: hey Jacob, this seems like a really basic question. You probably should do more research and go through more tutorials mate.

Comment: I do not believe so, trying that now.

Comment: Andrew, I am a very new HTML scripter. Should the ../buy be in CSS.css or file4.html?

Comment: Alright. When i tried <a href=/buy.html>Buy now.</a>, it gave me a big fat page not found.

Comment: @JacobSnyder a great tool to find solutions for 99% of beginners problems is google.com. Let's ask a question: `how to make a link to html local file`. Click first result and you've got your answer well described. Edit: assuming that they are in same directory - remove slash from your path.

Comment: @JacobSnyder if the file `buy.html` is in the same directory, you should do: `<a href="buy.html">Buy now.</a>` (without the slash).

Comment: Lol, does anyone thinks that OP - who is obviously new to SO - will mark a an answer as the correct one? This question should be tagged because of the lack of quality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will open the linked document in a new browser window/tab:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank" title="Visit My Page">Visit My Page</a>
```

You can use target="_top" to break out of the frame:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/html/file4.html" target="_top" title="Visit My Page">Visit My Page</a>
```

**Useful Tips Section**

Then, add a link to the bookmark ("Useful Products Section"), from within the same page:

```
<a href="#products" title="Visit the Useful products Section">Visit the Useful products Section</a>
```

Or, add a link to the bookmark ("Useful Tips Section"), from another page:
Example

```
<a href="file4.html#products" title="Visit the Useful products Section">Visit the Useful products Section</a>
```

--

```
<a href="page2.html" title="Link">Link</a>
```

If you have `page2.html` at the same level with folder then the path is:

```
<a href="../page2.html" title="Link">Link</a>
```

Comment: i tried <a href="buy.html" title="BuySprout">Link</a> but it still said page not found.

Comment: @JacobSnyder Are they in the same directory? - File format -> `.HTML` or `.HTM` ?

Comment: The file im trying to link to is named buy.html, but unsure if it is in the same directory

Comment: @JacobSnyder You using a hosting or localhost?

Comment: Im using repl.it, so most likely localhost?

Comment: @JacobSnyder Can you add your page source code in your question? or can you give your website address?

Comment: the website im using is https://repl.it/D1e9/2

Comment: @JacobSnyder You don't have a `buy.html` page

Comment: Sorry. Wrong link. Please try it agian.

Comment: @JacobSnyder I updated your codes but you dont working on repl.it. You need a hosting or localhost software

Comment: Ahh. Alright. Thanks a bunches.

Comment: @JacobSnyder Thank you for un-answered tick

Answer (score 0):

You'd just do:

```
<a href="filepath">click me</a>
```

If you ever put this on a website though, make sure you update the link to not be a file path and make it the url it goes too.

One note, your main `html` file should be `index.html`

Comment: You'll need to specify that its a file and not a url so href="file:///filename". This will work if buy.html is in the same directory as your other files. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837024/href-file-doesnt-work) out if you're still confused

Answer (score 0):

You can put a link to filename in `file4.html` like this:

```
<a href="buy.html">Link</a>
```

This, of course would only work if they were all in the same directory, otherwise, you would have to specify the relative path.

Comment: Okay. i tried that but it stated a Page Not Found. How do i add them to the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems that you want to jump to buy.html from your current page i.e file4.html. A simple  anchor tag with href set to relative path(if buy.html is in same or in any of dir in current dir) or absolute path(if it is present in totally different dir structure)
e.g 
`<a href="buy.html">Click to go Buy.html</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a href="buy.html">Click link here</a>` the href part is the page that it will direct you to and the click link here (or whatever you want to call it) is the actual link displayed on the webpage.

If the files are all in the same folder this way is correct, otherwise you must have the file path to the .html file