# open folder root with chrome receive not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to enable ficher on my **intranet** app that when a user will clicking a button the page will open a windows file explorer to folder specifide in the HREF attribute.

```
<a href="file://[the project folder]">Project Folder</a>
```

On Edge and Explorer that work fine.

In Chrome i get an error "not allowed to load local resource".

I understand the risk and why chrome blocked that option.
But it seems to me that this option (opening windows file explorer to local root) is so basic, that there must be a solution that will allow user to open the folder and still keep him safe (white list of sites allow to do so or someting like that).

I found the property "--allow-file-access-from-files" and i can ask the user to create a shortcut with this prorperty to access the application (its a intranet app)

1. it doesn't work for me (i use ver 60.X)
2. i dont want to risk the user that perhaps use the shortcut to open chrome and then redirect to another site.

Is there a solution i am missing out?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you try absolute path from your root directory? Kind of:

```
<a href="../your_directory1/your_directory2" target="_blank">Project Folder</a>
```

Being **your_directory1** the first directory from root, **your_directory2** after it, and so on...

The **../** call your path from the root of your server

Comment: I need it to open a new window folder explorer

Comment: I edited the question for opening it in a new window. Hoping it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the effort to help Elias, but i dont think that this is the issue of the problem. First i quite sure that the HREF must have a reference to FILE and not to a URL path.

Comment: You are welcome. Check this link, maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837024/href-file-doesnt-work. Cheers mate

Comment: In that case, the questioner had a problem in his HREF that point to a HTTP and then to a FILE. its a bad syntactic that all.

Comment: In that case, the questioner had a problem in his HREF that point to a HTTP and then to a FILE. its a bad syntactic that all. In my case, the syntactic is good (i belive) and work fine in IE, but due to security issue in chrome,  its denied.

Comment: Well, I surrender. I still recommend you to use my first approach. It is not a url path from the moment you are navigating in folder structure of your server. I coded an example of it in my computer and it works... If you finally dont find another solution, please, remember to accept my answer for keeping the SOF structure. Hoping you find the solution you desire. Cheers mate

Comment: If you succeed open a new windows file explorer from **CHROME** only by that line, its strange. Maybe my explain was not clear enough. if you will take the line i wrote (just change the "[the project folder]" to a UNC path to a folder in your pc) and try it in IE and in CHROME, you will see the different. Thanks again